# count nodes with attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to switch from XmlDocument to Linq, and am struggling to get what I want.

I have XML similar to this,

```
<root>
<Surfer Status='5'>
    <Name>Billy</Name>
    <County>Cornwall</County>
</Surfer>
<Surfer Status='5'>
    <Name>Tim</Name>
    <County>Cornwall</County>
</Surfer>
<Surfer Status='10'>
    <Name>Ryan</Name>
    <County>Devon</County>
</Surfer>
</root>
```

I can count  all the surfers like this.

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load("Surfers.xml");
int Total = X.Descendants("Surfer").Count();
```

I was hoping to count all the Surfers with a Status of 5 like this

```
int fives = X.Descendants["Surfer[@Status='5']").Count();
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work` ? Are you getting an error message ? Or are you simply not getting the expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Count` overload which takes a predicate

```
int fives = X.Descendants("Surfer").Count(x => x.Attribute("Status")?.Value == "5");
```

`x.Attribute("Status")` will retrieve the `Status` attribute from the `Surfer` element and `?.` operator prevents `NullReferenceException` if any of `Surfer` elements does not have `Status` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where`:

```
int fives = X.Descendants("Surfer").Where(s => (int)s.Attribute("Status") == 5).Count();
```

or if you really want to use XPath expression you can do it after adding `using System.Xml.XPath` and using `XPathSelectElements`:

```
int fives = X.XPathSelectElements("Surfer[@Status='5']").Count();
```